# Android application connection to database

Tags: android, web-services

I am new in android development.I am creating an android app in which the username and password need to be validated using Sql server 2005.I have read that to use SQL server 2005 in android app i will be needing a webservice.
Can u please give me guidelines as how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u want to extract data from external database in android then first u need to do database conectivity  in java and u need to fetch data from database as a xml formate and show that data in android through xml parsing. I hope this will help u.

Comment: can u give me a link where the sample code for my query is given?Will the data from the database returned in logcat ?